# Custom Attributes form in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, pyqt5

I'm trying to customize feature form with `ui` file, I followed https://nathanw.net/2011/09/05/qgis-tips-custom-feature-forms-with-python-logic/[1](https://nathanw.net/2011/09/05/qgis-tips-custom-feature-forms-with-python-logic/) but the attributes values still null when I added feature. [image]
This is ui file
[image]
So are there something I missed?

Comment: After you finish digitizing the geometry - does the custom form popup - or do you get the default instead? Did you set the layer Properties > Attribute Form to Provide ui-file and added the Edit UI filepath?

Comment: I have the custom popup. Yes I added UI filepath, and objectName in Qt designer are same name as the field